# How to close specific port with SuSEfirewall2?

Tags: linux, firewall, port-forwarding, sles

I'm opening specific ports in a SuSE 11 server to do ssh forwarding. After I finish, how do I close only the ports that I opened? I tried

```
SuSEfirewall2 close EXT TCP 4050
```

but it seems to close every port, not just 4050.
I've searched and found plenty of articles on opening ports, practically nothing on closing only specific ports.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation found within /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 ... take a look at DROP and REJECT entries in particular.  Make the edits there and and re-run SuSEconfig.

I think that's the easiest way.